# in TailwindCss how put buttons at bottom of wide-by-side divs with different content heights

Tags: vertical-alignment, tailwind-css

The Tailwindcss code below does a nice job of creating same-height cards.

How do I get all 3 buttons to align to the bottom of each card?

I expected adding "bottom-0" to the div holding the buttons would work, but I think the issue is "bottom" is relative it its parent, which is not the full height of the card.

[image]

quick playground:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/SX4Yu2OT3f

```
    .p-10.grid.grid-cols-1.sm:grid-cols-1.md:grid-cols-3.lg:grid-cols-3.xl:grid-cols-3.gap-5
      / Card 1
      .rounded.overflow-hidden.shadow-lg.bg-white
        = image_tag "http://via.placeholder.com/640x360", class: "w-full"
        .px-6.py-4
          .font-bold.text-xl.mb-2 Tagline 1
          %p.text-gray-700.text-base
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non recusandae, commodi repudiandae exercitationem, architecto assumenda nobis doloribus, deleniti obcaecati quaerat at quam! Rerum vitae quam culpa! Voluptates dolore sint. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non recusandae, commodi repudiandae exercitationem, architecto assumenda nobis doloribus, deleniti obcaecati quaerat at quam! Rerum vitae quam culpa! Voluptates dolore sint.  
        .px-6.pt-4.pb-2.text-left
          = link_to "learn more", "#", class: "btn btn-small btn-tertiary"
      / Card 2
      .rounded.overflow-hidden.shadow-lg.bg-white
        = image_tag "http://via.placeholder.com/640x360", class: "w-full"
        .px-6.py-4
          .font-bold.text-xl.mb-2 Tagline 2
          %p.text-gray-700.text-base
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non recusandae, commodi repudiandae exercitationem, architecto assumenda nobis doloribus, deleniti obcaecati quaerat at quam! Rerum vitae quam culpa! Voluptates dolore sint. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non recusandae, commodi repudiandae exercitationem, 
        .px-6.pt-4.pb-2.text-center
          = link_to "try it!", "#", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary"
      / Card 3
      .rounded.overflow-hidden.shadow-lg.bg-white
        = image_tag "http://via.placeholder.com/640x360", class: "w-full"
        .px-6.py-4
          .font-bold.text-xl.mb-2 Tagline 3
          %p.text-gray-700.text-base
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non recusandae, commodi repudiandae exercitationem, architecto assumenda nobis doloribus, deleniti obcaecati quaerat at quam! Rerum vitae quam culpa! Voluptates dolore sint. 

        .px-6.pt-4.pb-2.text-right
          = link_to "find it", "#", class: "btn btn-small btn-secondary"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a `flex flex-col` classes to your card and `mt-auto` to button wrapper

```
.p-10.grid.grid-cols-1.sm:grid-cols-1.md:grid-cols-3.lg:grid-cols-3.xl:grid-cols-3.gap-5
      / Card 1
      .rounded.overflow-hidden.shadow-lg.bg-white.flex.flex-col
        = image_tag "http://via.placeholder.com/640x360", class: "w-full"
        .px-6.py-4
          .font-bold.text-xl.mb-2 Tagline 1
          %p.text-gray-700.text-base
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non recusandae, commodi repudiandae exercitationem, architecto assumenda nobis doloribus, deleniti obcaecati quaerat at quam! Rerum vitae quam culpa! Voluptates dolore sint. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non recusandae, commodi repudiandae exercitationem, architecto assumenda nobis doloribus, deleniti obcaecati quaerat at quam! Rerum vitae quam culpa! Voluptates dolore sint.  
        .px-6.pt-4.pb-2.text-left.mt-auto
          = link_to "learn more", "#", class: "btn btn-small btn-tertiary"
```

Comment: does not align buttons to the bottom of each card

Comment: `mt-auto` not `mx-auto`. It works in playtailwind example

Comment: confirmed here is playground showing accepted answer: https://play.tailwindcss.com/3XUqMFzz68

Answer (score 0):

Give position-relative class to your wrapper box

```
.rounded.overflow-hidden.shadow-lg.bg-white.relative
```

and then set position-absolute & bottom-0 to your button

```
      = link_to "learn more", "#", class: "btn btn-small btn-tertiary bottom-0 absolute"
```

Comment: extremely close, but breaks the text-XXXXX to position the buttons horizontally. Worked to add left-0 and right-0 to the left and right buttons ... but any idea how to center the middle one?

Comment: create a div wrapper for your button and set width: 100% and text-align: center and then put your button into this div